# I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error with the Google Wallet Objects API

Tags: android-pay

I'm getting the following when trying to authenticate using OAuth2 using the Java client library:

```
Error:
Code was 403
Msg: Forbidden
{
""error"": {
""errors"": [
{
""domain"": ""global"",
""reason"": ""insufficientPermissions"",
""message"": ""Insufficient Permission""
}
],
""code"": 403,
""message"": ""Insufficient Permission""
}
}
```

What could be causing this "Insufficient Permission" error?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you edit your question to provide the context of what you're doing to get the error?  We need more information in order to help you.

Comment: If you're getting this error when calling one of the Google Wallet APIs, please make sure to let us know which one you're using and also if that's the response you're getting please also let us know what's your request if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Google Wallet Objects API, make sure that you share your Account in the Merchant Account with the Service Account Email Address (the one you got when you created your credentials - you can get this one from the cloud console https://cloud.google.com/console, the one that ends with @developer.gserviceaccount.com)

Login to the Merchant Dashboard, click on Account Management and then click on Share. Add the email to the list of users.

You'll also want to share your merchant account with any users you want to give preview access to your classes and discoverables.